# More than one parameter in clostache/render function?

Tags: mysql, clojure

I am new to Clojure and I am trying to make a page where you can see all the news that are in a table on the left, and only sports news on the right of the page. I tried to add a new parameter to the clostache/render:

```
(defn render-template [template-file params param]
  (clostache/render (read-template template-file) params param))

(defn welcome []
  (render-template "index" {:sports (model/justSports)} {:news (model/all)}))
```

where the model/all and model/justSports are:

```
    (defn all []
  (j/query mysql-db
    (s/select * :news)))

(defn justSports []
  (j/query mysql-db
    (s/select * :news ["genre = ?" "sports"])))
```

and the news should be shown like this:

```
<div style="background-color: #D3D3D3; width: 450px; height: 800px; position: absolute; right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 25px;">
       <sections>
         {{#sports}}
         <h2>{{title}}</h2>
         <p>{{text}}<p>
         {{/sports}}
       </sections>
       </div>

      <div class="container"  style="width: 500px; height: 800px; position: absolute; left: 20px;">
      <h1>Listing Posts</h1>
      <sections>
         {{#news}}
           <h2>{{title}}</h2>
           <p>{{text}}<p>
         {{/news}}
     </sections>
  </div>
```

But it doesn't work. It just shows the data from the first parameter on the page. What do you think, how can I make this work?

P.S.
Don't mind the ugly css, I will work on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should make it work:

```
(defn render-template [template-file params]
  (clostache/render (read-template template-file) params))

(defn welcome []
  (render-template "index" {:sports (model/justSports)
                            :news (model/all)}))
```

[`render`](https://github.com/fhd/clostache/blob/master/src/clostache/parser.clj#L364-L373) has three "arities":

> ```
> (defn render
>   "Renders the template with the data and, if supplied, partials."
>   ([template]
>      (render template {} {}))
>   ([template data]
>      (render template data {}))
>   ([template data partials]
>      (replace-all (render-template template data partials)
>                   [["\\\\\\{\\\\\\{" "{{"]
>                    ["\\\\\\}\\\\\\}" "}}"]])))
> ```

You were calling the 3-arity overload which takes `[template data partials]`, so the second map with the `:news` key was being taken as the `partials` by clostache. You want to call the 2-arity version which takes just `[template data]`, passing one map with keys `:news` & `:sports`.